# Convert a stringyfied 2 dimensional array back to a python object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2 dimensional array, but the array is in a stringyfied form. I would like to convert it back to a python object so I can access the context

```
stringedArray = "[[4.50000e+01, 2.24000e+02, 1.70000e+02, 3.46000e+02, 9.40884e-01, 0.00000e+00],
        [2.91000e+02, 0.00000e+00, 4.69000e+02, 5.90000e+01, 9.19830e-01, 2.00000e+00],
        [4.71000e+02, 1.20000e+01, 5.22000e+02, 9.20000e+01, 9.04654e-01, 1.00000e+00],
        [1.93000e+02, 6.90000e+01, 2.64000e+02, 1.35000e+02, 8.95800e-01, 1.00000e+00],
        [1.80000e+01, 1.13000e+02, 1.29000e+02, 1.79000e+02, 8.90799e-01, 0.00000e+00],
        [9.90000e+01, 1.39000e+02, 2.78000e+02, 2.09000e+02, 2.62809e-01, 2.00000e+00]]"

 arrayObject = #convertion code here

 print(arrayObject[3][5])
 # prints: 1 or 1.00000
```

Is there a function in python similar to javascripts JSON.parse which converts a string to a object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894269/4046632

Answer (score 0):

```py
from json import loads
stringed_list = "[[1, 2], [3, 4]]"
as_list = loads(stringed_list)
print(type(as_list)) # <class 'list'>
print(as_list[0][0]) # 1
```

edited according to comments. If you're working with a file, use
`json.load(file)` instead.

Comment: Please, don't suggest `eval` for that. Use either `json.loads()` (if working with string literal) or `json.load()` for working directly with file or `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: OP sample is valid json, i.e. no need to "make it valid JSON"